# Cannot add Unity modules to 2020.3.27f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I downloaded Unity seperate from Unity Hub and when I try to add module I can't find the option. I am using Hub 3.0.1. I already tried editing the editors.json file. When i switch manuel to false and go back to Hub, I got this error:

> Unity 2020.3.27f1 is no longer available from the Hub. For a better
> experience, we recommend the latest LTS (Long-Term Support) version.
> You can find all Editor versions in the Installs Archive.

Is there anything I can do to add modules except installing Unity Editor from the Hub? Thank you!

Edit: I found a solution that worked like a charm. Download Unity [your-desired-unity-version-here] installer from Unity website. Open the setup. It will ask you what to install and where. Untick unity package and just tick the modules you want to install. Next choose the current unity installation folder and voila. You are good to go.

Comment: Regarding your edit and solution, don't forget _you_ can post your own answers and assuming there are no better posts accept it gaining reputation in the process! Just be sure to follow the guidelines when posting.  :)

Comment: ...oh and don't add _"[SOLVED]"_ to question titles.  Stack Overflow isn't a _forum_

Comment: @MickyD thank you for the clarification. What i wondered is that people might see the headline and click it to help me only to find it is already solved. That's why I put it in the title. :)

Comment: If you found a solution feel free to answer your own question with it so other users can more easily find the answer :)